# How to do _mm256_maskstore_epi8() in C/C++?

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

### The problem

What I am trying to do is, if I have a vector of 27 (not 32!) `int8_t`:

`x = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26}`

I want to first cyclic-shift it to the right by n (**not a constant**), e.g. if n=1:

`x2 = {26,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25}`

Then this vector is used to perform some very complex calculation, but for simplicity, let's assume that the next step is just to cyclic-shift it back to the left by n, and store it to the memory. So I should have a new vector of 27 `int8_t`:

`y = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26}`

So there're thousands of such vectors and performance is very critical here. The CPU that we're using has AVX2 support so we want to use it to speed things up.

### My current solution

To get `x2`, I use two `_mm256_loadu_si256()` with a `_mm256_blendv_epi8()`:

```
int8_t x[31+27+31];
for(int i=0; i<27; i++){
    x[31+i] = i;
}
__m256i mask = _mm256_set_epi32 (0x0, 0x00800000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0);
__m256i x_second_part = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)(x+31+1));  //{1,2,...,26}
__m256i x_first_part  = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)(x+31-26)); //{0}
__m256i x2            = _mm256_blendv_epi8(x_second_part, x_first_part, mask); //{1,2,...,26, 0}
int8_t y[31+27+31];
_mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)(y+31-26), x2);
_mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)(y+31+1), x2);
```

The reason why the `x` and `y` are declared to be of size `[31+27+31]` is that in this case `_mm256_loadu_si256()` and `_mm256_storeu_si256()` won't cause segfault.

And I can get the value of `y` by:

```
for(int i=0; i<27; i++){
    cout << (int)y[31+i] << ' ';
}
```

### The new problem

Unfortunately all the vectors must be continuous in memory, for example, if there are totally two vectors that need to be processed:

```
x = {[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];
     [27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53]};
```

Then I cannot just use `_mm256_storeu_si256()` to put the value of `y` back to memory because when the value of the second vector is written to memory it will overwrite some values of the first vector:

```
int8_t x[31+27+27+31];
int8_t y[31+27+27+31];
for(int i=0; i<27*2; i++){
    x[31+i] = i;
}
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    __m256i mask = _mm256_set_epi32 (0x0, 0x00800000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0);
    __m256i x_second_part = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)(x+31+27*i+1));  //{1,2,...,26}
    __m256i x_first_part  = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)(x+31+27*i-26)); //{0}
    __m256i x2            = _mm256_blendv_epi8(x_second_part, x_first_part, mask); //{1,2,...,26, 0}
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)(y+31+27*i-26), x2);
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)(y+31+27*i+1), x2);
}
for(int i=0; i<27; i++){
    cout << (int)y[31+i] << ' ';
}cout << endl;
for(int i=0; i<27; i++){
    cout << (int)y[31+27+i] << ' ';
}cout << endl;
```

will output

```
0 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53
```

instead of

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53
```

So I was thinking of using maskstore. But in the [Intel Intrinsic Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX,AVX2&cats=Load,Store,) I couldn't find `_mm256_maskstore_epi8`. This leads me back to the topic:

#### How to do _mm256_maskstore_epi8() in C/C++?

Comment: It doesn't exist.  The only byte-granularity mask-store is the 128b-only [MASKMOVDQU](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MASKMOVDQU.html), which has NT semantics (weakly-ordered, bypasses cache, evicts the data you use it on).  You usually don't want that.  [VPMASKMOVD/Q (epi32/64)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VPMASKMOV.html) are the only available sizes of 256b mask-store (and of mask-store without NT semantics, so even unpacking to two 128b lanes doesn't help.  Even the VEX encoding of the SSE instruction, VMASKMOVDQU has NT semantics).

Comment: Is a non-atomic read-modify-write the overlapping final 5 bytes ok?  If so, load them and merge.  (Or the preceding 5 bytes?)

Comment: I think that using of 128-bit vector is a better solution, because you can perform saving/loading without exit from 27-byte array.

Comment: Oh right, do two overlapping 128b stores!  Yeah that should be good.  Use PALIGNR to set up for the overlapped store.

Comment: @PeterCordes. Your 'two overlapping 128b stores' sounds like the way to go. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: It's Ermlg's idea; I think that's what he meant.

Comment: @PeterCordes Just curious. Have you every benchmarked overlapping stores? It's something that I do as well, but usually at the end of a long loop where it's not in a performance-critical. Something about dumping that complexity on the chip tells me there might be a stall. But I've personally never benchmarked it.

Comment: @Mysticial: no, I haven't :(.  Given my mental model of how CPUs work internally, I think the store buffer should be able to handle it just fine when the destination is write-only.  But you're right, it's probably a good idea to test this at some point.  Still, I've seen other people suggest it, too, for stuff like left-packing with `dst += popcnt(mask);`

Comment: @hhy: *I use two `_mm256_maskloadu_si256()`*... I think you mean use `_mm256_loadu_si256()`, like you show in your code.  I didn't make an edit myself in case you actually meant something else.

Comment: @PeterCordes. You are correct. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another  implementation of cyclic-shift inside 27-bytes vector with using AVX2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

const __m256i K0 = _mm256_setr_epi8(
    0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70,
    0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0);

const __m256i K1 = _mm256_setr_epi8(
    0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0,
    0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70);

inline const __m256i Shuffle(const __m256i & value, const __m256i & shuffle)
{
    return _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_shuffle_epi8(value, _mm256_add_epi8(shuffle, K0)),
        _mm256_shuffle_epi8(_mm256_permute4x64_epi64(value, 0x4E), _mm256_add_epi8(shuffle, K1)));
}

__m256i shuffles[27];

void Init()
{
    uint8_t * p = (uint8_t *)shuffles;
    for (int s = 0; s < 27; ++s)
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
            p[s*32 + i] = i < 27 ? (27 + i - s)%27 : i;
}

void CyclicShift27(const uint8_t * src, size_t shift, uint8_t * dst)
{
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)dst,  Shuffle(_mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)src), shuffles[shift]));
}

int main()
{
    Init();
    uint8_t src[32] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31 }, dst[32];
    for (int j = 0; j < 27; ++j)
    {
        CyclicShift27(src, j, dst);
        std::cout << "\t";
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            std::cout << (int)dst[i] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
    26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 27 28 29 30 31
    25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 27 28 29 30 31
    24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 27 28 29 30 31
    23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 27 28 29 30 31
    22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 27 28 29 30 31
    21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 27 28 29 30 31
    20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 27 28 29 30 31
    19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 27 28 29 30 31
    18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 27 28 29 30 31
    17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 27 28 29 30 31
    16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 27 28 29 30 31
    15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 27 28 29 30 31
    14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 27 28 29 30 31
    13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 27 28 29 30 31
    12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 27 28 29 30 31
    11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 27 28 29 30 31
    10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 27 28 29 30 31
    9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 27 28 29 30 31
    8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 27 28 29 30 31
    7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 27 28 29 30 31
    6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 27 28 29 30 31
    5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 27 28 29 30 31
    4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 27 28 29 30 31
    3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 27 28 29 30 31
    2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 27 28 29 30 31
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 27 28 29 30 31
```

It looks more simple than my previous answer.

Comment: Note that `const __m256i K0 = _mm256_setr_epi8(...)` at global scope is actually worse than having that inside your function.  For some reason, gcc doesn't evaluate `_mm256_setr_epi8` at compile time, so it generates a constructor-like function to copy from a read-only constant version of that data to your global in the BSS.  Just using `const __m256i K0` inside every function that needs it is what I've observed to be best, since compilers do the same kind of merging on constants that they do for identical string literals, so there's only one copy in the executable.

Comment: Is it possible to overlap the different shuffle masks, instead of having 27 * 32B of vector constants?  That's 864B of L1 cache, spanning 14 cache lines.  That's not *too* bad, but spending an extra instruction or two to generate masks smaller constants might be worth it (if it's possible, IDK), esp. if this is used as part of other code that also uses cache.

Comment: You could store the whole variable part of the shuffle mask in ~52 bytes, like `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26` and just do an unaligned load at a byte-granular offset to load it. Then you'd need to fix up the last five bytes which are the same (`27 28 29 30 31`) for every vector. That would probably be easier if they were 4 bytes (a `movd` or a dword blend could do it). You could `pshufb` it in, but of course port 5 is already gonna be under stress here...

Answer (score 0):

I have made an implementation of cyclic-shift inside 27-bytes vector with using of SSSE3:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tmmintrin.h>

union Shuffle
{
    uint8_t s[64];
    __m128i v[4];
};

Shuffle shuffles[27];

int Shift(int value)
{
    return (value >= 0 && value < 16) ? value : -1;
}

void Init()
{
    for (int s = 0; s < 27; ++s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        {
            shuffles[s].s[0 + i] = s < 16 ? Shift(i - s) : Shift(i - s + 27);
            shuffles[s].s[16 + i] = Shift(16 + i - s);
            shuffles[s].s[32 + i] = Shift(11 + i - s);
            shuffles[s].s[48 + i] = s < 11 ? Shift(i - s) : Shift(i - s + 27);
        }
    }
}

void CyclicShift27(const uint8_t * src, size_t shift, uint8_t * dst)
{
    __m128i srcLo = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(src + 0));
    __m128i srcHi = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(src + 11));
    __m128i dstLo = _mm_or_si128(_mm_shuffle_epi8(srcLo, shuffles[shift].v[0]), _mm_shuffle_epi8(srcHi, shuffles[shift].v[1]));
    __m128i dstHi = _mm_or_si128(_mm_shuffle_epi8(srcLo, shuffles[shift].v[2]), _mm_shuffle_epi8(srcHi, shuffles[shift].v[3]));
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(dst + 0), dstLo);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(dst + 11), dstHi);
}

int main()
{
    Init();
    uint8_t src[27] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26 }, dst[27];
    for (int j = 0; j < 27; ++j)
    {
        CyclicShift27(src, j, dst);
        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
            std::cout << (int)dst[i] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It output:

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
    26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
    25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
    24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
    23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
    22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
    21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
    20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
    19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
    18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
    17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
    16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
    15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
    14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
    13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
    12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
    11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
    7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
    6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4 5
    5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3 4
    4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2 3
    3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1 2
    2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0 1
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 0
```

I hope it will be useful.

Comment: So, you're essentially suggesting that OP use 128-bit instructions since a 256-instruction is unavailable?

Comment: Excellent solution for cyclic-shifting inside a 27-bytes vector I would say! But mixing SSE with AVX may cause some performance penalty? Perhaps I should do some profiling before deciding which way to go.

Comment: IIRC the SSE instructions have new VEX-encoded equivalents in AVX, so it's just a matter of using them. In assembly that's via the 3-arg versions, generally, but with intrinsics it's a bit more complex and depends on compiler switches or something?